# Connect to DocumentDB with NodeJS using keep-alive

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb

Is there any way to specify the option keep-alive to connect to DocumentDB using the NodeJS SDK (http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-node)?

Comment: I am using the version 5.6.0 of NodeJS

Comment: Are you primarily concerned with the node.js socket timing out before it receives a response from DocumentDB? If so, you can specify a timeout of 10 seconds to cover any DocumentDB query that I've run. If not, why would want to keep anything else alive? The node.js SDK is a relatively thin wrapper around the DocumentDB REST API and is by design stateless and async. Unless I'm misunderstanding, in which case, please accept my apology.

Comment: I am using the DocumentDB with StrawJS framework. The problem isn't the reponse timeout. I need to keep the conection alive because my code need to run continuously and make connection do documentDB at any time a request is sent to a StrawJS node.

Comment: I answered below. You might want to consider updating your question with a description of your environment (mention StrawJS) and what you are trying to accomplish. If you have any code already written, it's usually good to include that also. This approach will get you a better response on SO than asking about a particular capability ("specify the option keep-alive").

Comment: Ok, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need keep alive to use StrawJS, which is good because DocumentDB doesn't offer anything like that. Rather you can poll periodically. Adapting the example on the StrawJS website:

```
var straw = require('straw')
module.exports = straw.node({
  timer: null,
  opts: {interval: 1000},  // Set your polling interval here
  initialize: function(opts, done){
    this.opts.interval = opts && opts.interval || 1000;
    done();
  },
  start: function(done) {
    this.timer = setInterval(this.ping.bind(this), this.opts.interval);
    done(false);
  },
  stop: function(done) {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
    done(false);
  },
  data: function() {
    var queryIterator = client.queryDocuments(<your query config>);
    queryIterator.toArray(function(err, response) {
      manipulatedResponse = <some manipulation>(response);
      this.output({'data': manipulatedResponse});
    })
  }
});
```